# BottomNavigationView text overlaps on icon

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have used `BottomNavigationView` in my app, but the text of menu item overlaps on menu icon in small devices as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Edit:
Here is the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String SELECTED_ITEM = "arg_selected_item";

    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNav;
    private int mSelectedItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(mBottomNav);
        mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                selectFragment(item);
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItem selectedItem;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSelectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, 0);
            selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(mSelectedItem);
        } else {
            selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
        }
        selectFragment(selectedItem);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, mSelectedItem);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        MenuItem homeItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
        if (mSelectedItem != homeItem.getItemId()) {
            // select home item
            selectFragment(homeItem);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
        // init corresponding fragment
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_explore:
                pushFragment(new ExploreFragment());
                break;

            case R.id.menu_how_it_works:
                pushFragment(new HowItWorksFragment());
                break;

            case R.id.menu_contact_us:
                pushFragment(new ContactUsFragment());
                break;

            case R.id.menu_profile:
                pushFragment(new MyProfileFragment());
                break;
        }

        // update selected item
        mSelectedItem = item.getItemId();

        // uncheck the other items.
        for (int i = 0; i < mBottomNav.getMenu().size(); i++) {
            MenuItem menuItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(i);
            menuItem.setChecked(menuItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId());
        }

        updateToolbarText(item.getTitle());

    }

    protected void pushFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment == null)
            return;

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (ft != null) {
                ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateToolbarText(CharSequence text) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How to resolve this issue ?

**Please Help!!**

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan please check the update.

Comment: How about the XML ?

Comment: Did you try shorter text? Did result is the same?

Comment: @Damien check the update

Comment: @oguzhand Yes.. shorter text works but I can't use short text..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use long texts on bottom bar. It's out of guideline. Bottom Bar is not developed to use like that.

[image]

> Text labels provide short, meaningfully definitions to bottom
>   navigation icons. Avoid long text labels as these labels do not
>   truncate or wrap.

Read all documentation and usage descriptions at this [Source](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage).